# Difference in behavior on optimization

Tags: c++, reference

I get different results for the following program, depending on whether I have optimizations enabled or not.

I was expecting to see 10 printed out, but when I have optimizations enabled, I get random values printed.

This happens on both GCC and Clang. It looks like the constructor is getting optimized out, because if I add an output statement in the constructor, I get the expected results even with optimization. Could somebody please explain what I am missing? Is it undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct wrapper
{
    const int &ref;
    wrapper(const char &t):ref(t)
    {//cout<<"";  If I un-comment this statement, I get the expected result
    }
};


int main() {
    int a=10;
    char c=a;
    cout<<wrapper(c).ref<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be undefined behavior since gcc says:

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'wrapper::wrapper(const char&)':
prog.cc:8:33: warning: a temporary bound to 'wrapper::ref' only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]
     wrapper(const char &t):ref(t)
                                 ^
```

Comment: Note: OP would have expected output by changing `const int &ref` into `const char &ref`.

Comment: The expected output is 10 (ASCII for newline). By using char reference, the newline gets printed. The whole idea was to try and get the integer value for the char printed (I do know about casts!).  I settled for having an actual int member in the wrapper.

Comment: @user2308211: Replacing `const int& ref;` by `int value;` would also solve your issue.